# Buffer for reading script in bash

Tags: bash

I have a problem with running script under bash. When the script is started and while it is executing some long operation *and* I change that script, after long operation is finished bash is reading rest of the script and fails with silly errors like below:

```
test.sh: line 1093: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
test.sh: line 1098: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

If I run the same script (without further changes) there are no error whatsoever.

I suspect there is a buffered reading done by bash. Is there something I can do to make bash reading script in whole?

Comment: Can you show us those lines from 1093 to 1098, without it one can't understand much of the problem

Comment: If you have to change it while it's running, change the start of it so it copies itself somewhere else and execs the copy with the original parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Bash reads the script line by line. If you change the length of a line that's before the current position, bash will start reading the next line from the middle of a line and most probably fail.

Don't change the source of a running script, make a copy.

Answer (score 0):

Probable duplicate of the question asked:

[Edit shell script while it's running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398258/edit-shell-script-while-its-running/3399850#3399850)

In particular, I like the answer at the comment referenced in the link (involves use of the `source` command and seperate `.sh` files).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: to add {} like

```
#!/bin/bash
{
code goes here
}
```

This way everything inside {} will be read into memory.