# Edit PowerShell script while it's running

Tags: windows, powershell, shell

Apparently, editing a Linux shell script while it is being executed results in an [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3398258/edit-shell-script-while-its-running).

What happens when you edit a PowerShell script while it is being executed?

Comment: Nothing happens. PowerShell reads in, and parses, the entire script before executing it

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Is this behavior of all the PowerShell versions under all the supported platforms?

Comment: At least since 3.0, I can't remember (and don't have access to a copy of) version 2.0

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell parses everything from top to bottom once and never goes back again.
Once it's in, it's in :)
If you need to reload as example, a PowerShell module into a current session you have to use the -Force flag.